# ARFF dataset. Did I train my decision tree model correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, python, cart

I am new to ML and coding so I thought a fun first project would be to create a decision tree that can detect phishing links.

I plan to use two datasets. [This](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/phishing+websites) is the first one which I am currently working with. If I think it would be wise to further enhance the training, I will use [this](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/h3cgnj8hft/1).

An ARFF file is in this kind of format:

[image]

[image]

What I did before writing any code was I deleted everything from `@data` and up because initially I thought that scikit isn't interested in strings it wants to see the numbers. What I am left with is a text file of lots of numbers, that is eventually neatly formatted inside a csv.

Here is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Train decision tree to detect phishing
# Dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Phishing+Websites#

import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import *
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from IPython.display import Image
import pydotplus


# Put the arff dataset into a csv
def saveDataToCSV(inf, outf):
   arffin = csv.reader(open(inf, 'r'), delimiter=',')
   arffout = csv.writer(open(outf, 'w'))
   arffout.writerows(arffin)


# Train decision tree with initial dataset, Initially ~90.5% accuracy
 def traintree(incsv):
   training_data = np.genfromtxt(incsv, delimiter=',', dtype=np.int32)  # 
   load the dataset
   inputs = training_data[:, :-1]  # all attributes except the last one
   outputs = training_data[:, -1]  # last attribute

   # Divide dataset into training and testing
   training_inputs = inputs[:2000]
   training_outputs = outputs[:2000]
   testing_inputs = inputs[2000:]
   testing_outputs = outputs[2000:]

   classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
   classifier.fit(training_inputs, training_outputs)
   predictions = classifier.predict(testing_inputs)
   #accuracy = 100.0 * accuracy_score(testing_outputs, predictions)

   '''
   # Currently unpruned and doesnt make much sense
   dot_data = StringIO()
   export_graphviz(classifier, out_file=dot_data, filled=True, 
   rounded=True, special_characters=True)
   graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
   graph.write_png('phishing.png')
   Image(graph.create_png())
   '''

def main():
    saveDataToCSV("dataset.arff", "dataset.csv")
    traintree("dataset.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It trained at 90% accuracy. As I started reading more about ARFF, people seem to use a program called Weka to train from ARFF datasets. Noticing that people *dont delete everything from @data on up* like I did, made me think I made a mistake deleting everything except the numbers under `@data`.

What should I do differently? Did I train my decision tree incorrectly?

Any additional tips/advice you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Decision trees dont care about meta information (everything above '@data'). Weka is just using that to provide the user with more information like column name etc. for example in their GUI. Model perfomance is not affected by this.

Comment: If 90% accuracy is not a lot, and you expected more - then probably you should rethink your train-test-split choice. Splitting the data to "first 2000 train - last 2000 test" is not a good idea. Consider scikit-learn libs for that (or even cv).

Comment: I expected 90%+ accuracy, I am following a tutorial. To clarify, _how_ does the decision tree know what a phishing link looks like from thousands of `0, 0, 1, -1, 0 .. etc` without any context from the `@attribute` section?
Tutorial I am looking at:
https://hub.packtpub.com/using-machine-learning-for-phishing-domain-detection-tutorial/

Comment: how did they train-test split? The last column is always the class label for Weka by default. You can test it by yourself: Run weka with an arff file: with and without meta information.

Comment: Weka throws an error when I delete the `@attribute` section so I believe it is necessary to keep it. Through some research I found a python library that allows me to import arff files so I am going to edit my code above. Also am going to use the other dataset with 10,000 examples and 48 features split 60/20/20 for training/validating/testing